# Oracle: Compare overlapping relations

Tags: oracle, set

I want to compare two records based on rows in a related table. Let's say I have two tables, FOOS and BARS.

```
FOOS

+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
+----+

BARS 

+--------+-------+
| foo_id | value |
+--------+-------+
| 1      |   1   |
| 1      |   2   |
| 1      |   3   |
| 2      |   1   |
| 2      |   2   |  
| 3      |   3   |
+--------+-------+
```

So each Foo has a collection of bars.

- Foo 1 has bar values 1, 2, 3
- Foo 2 has bar values 1, 2
- Foo 3 has bar values 3

I want to be able to find out, from a FOO id, which other FOOS have the same ids.

- Foo 1 doesn't have any matching foos.
- Foo 2 matches Foo 1, because Foo 1 has bar values 1 and 2.
- Foo 3 matches Foo 1, because Foo 1 has bar values 3.

I'd like to present the result as a table like this:

```
+---------+----------+
| src_foo | targ_foo |
+---------+----------+
|    2    |    1     |
|    3    |    1     |
+---------+----------+
```

---

Here's a DB setup script providing the above data:

```
create table foos (id number(32) not null) ;
create table bars (foo_id number(32) not null, val number(32) not null);

insert into foos (id) values (1);
insert into foos (id) values (2);
insert into foos (id) values (3);

insert into bars (val, foo_id) values (1, 1);
insert into bars (val, foo_id) values (2, 1);
insert into bars (val, foo_id) values (3, 1);
insert into bars (val, foo_id) values (1, 2);
insert into bars (val, foo_id) values (2, 2);
insert into bars (val, foo_id) values (3, 3);
```

Comment: In all problems, you must think about `null` and about duplicates. In this case: is `id` primary key (and therefore unique and not null) in the `foos` table? Is the `foo_id` column foreign key pointing to `foos.id`, and is it not nullable? Can `bars.value` ever be `null` - and if it can, how should that be handled, with regard to your comparison problem? Finally, is `(bars.foo_id, bars.value)` unique, or can there be duplicates? (That is, can the same value appear more than once for the same `foo_id`?) - and if so, how should that be handled with regard to your comparisons?

Comment: @mathguy foos.id is unique and not null. bars.val is not nullable. bars only has unique rows.

Comment: Sorry - I see that some of the questions (those regarding `null`) were already answered in the `create table` statements. I hadn't looked at them yet when I asked my questions.

Comment: If the value of id = 3 was 1, what should the output be? id 3 would match both 1 and 2 in that case. Should we output both, or just one of those target foo ids? If the latter, which should we return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this using `MULTISET` operators and `COLLECT` function.

Create a  nested table `TYPE`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE numtab as TABLE OF NUMBER(32);
```

**Edit**

We could use `SUBMULTISET` operator for nested tables, which is more straightforward and does the same as below method. Thanks @mathguy

```
WITH t AS (
     SELECT foo_id,
            CAST(COLLECT(val) AS numtab) x
     FROM bars
     GROUP BY foo_id
)   
SELECT a.foo_id a_foo_id,
       b.foo_id b_foo_id
FROM t a
CROSS JOIN t b
WHERE a.x != b.x 
AND a.x SUBMULTISET OF b.x
```

Another method

```
WITH t AS (
     SELECT foo_id,
            CAST(COLLECT(val) AS numtab) x
     FROM bars
     GROUP BY foo_id
) 
select a_foo_id,b_foo_id FROM
( SELECT a.foo_id a_foo_id,
         b.foo_id b_foo_id,
         a.x a_x,
         b.x b_x,
         a.x MULTISET INTERSECT b.x as i
  FROM t a
    CROSS JOIN t b
  WHERE a.x != b.x
) where i = a_x
  ;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=23e02874421c188e326611475f6a2989)

Comment: Why not use the `submultiset` comparison condition directly?

Comment: @mathguy : Ah! Thanks.. I was searching for it , just couldn't recall.

Comment: Note that `submultiset` is specifically a *nested table* function - it is not, more generally, a *collection* function. Collections include nested tables, but also varrays. It would be really helpful if `submultiset` worked on varrays, or if there was an easy way to convert a varray to a nested table (both of which should be trivial for Oracle to implement, but it simply has not). Or if Oracle had something similar to `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST`, but of nested table type rather than varray. Then we wouldn't need to create our own nested table type, we could use `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST` instead.

Comment: ... and, sorry, `submultiset` is not a *funtion*, it is a comparison operator (a logical condition, similar to an inequality).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative that doesn't use nested tables:

```
SELECT src_foo, targ_foo
FROM   (SELECT b1.foo_id targ_foo, b2.foo_id src_foo, b2.foo_id_val_count
        FROM   bars b1
               INNER JOIN (SELECT foo_id, value, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY foo_id) foo_id_val_count FROM bars) b2 ON b1.foo_id != b2.foo_id AND b1.value = b2.value)
GROUP BY src_foo, targ_foo, foo_id_val_count
HAVING foo_id_val_count = COUNT(*)
ORDER BY src_foo, targ_foo;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d1124734edcb943c0cc8b1166bd9f03f

It works by first finding out how many rows are there for each foo_id and then comparing each foo_id to the other foo_ids, where the vals are the same.

If the same number of rows is returned as there are rows for that foo_id, you know all the vals are present in that foo_id. If not, then we don't care about them.

Whether this is faster than the nested table solution or not is up to you to find out for your data, etc.